# calling mulit-function in one app

Tags: android, gps, orientation

I'm working with an app in which I need to get three kind of data and save it:

1. My external sensor data
2. Orientation data
3. GPS data

is it possible to do that only using one button?

here is my code structure

```
private Button.OnClickListener myButton2_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();      
        timer.schedule(new WriteFile(), 1000, 1000);
    }
};

public class WriteFile extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
    @Override
    public void run() {
        VGNMData();
        OriData();
        GPSData();
    }

    private void OriData() {
        //get oridata here
    }

    private void GPSData() {
    //get GPSData here
    }                                        

    private void VGNMData() {
        //get VGNMData here
    }

}   }   }
```

Is this structure correct?
Or is there a more efficienct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the best way to go about it, since the whole point of using another thread is to not do work on the UI thread. This might work:

```
    public class WriteFile extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        VGNMData();
        OriData();
        GPSData();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {        
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do UI related stuff here
            }
        }
    }
    private void OriData() {
        //get oridata here
    }

    private void GPSData() {
        //get GPSData here
    }                                        

    private void VGNMData() {
        //get VGNMData here
    }
    }
```

However, you should look in to an AsyncTask (or AsyncTaskLoader), depending on how long those three functions take to execute. Here is how that might work:

```
    private Button.OnClickListener myButton2_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AcquireDataTask().execute();
    }
    };



    class AcquireDataTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Boolean> {
        private void OriData() {
            //get oridata here
        }

        private void GPSData() {
            //get GPSData here
        }                                        

        private void VGNMData() {
            //get VGNMData here
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground (Object... data) {
            VGNMData();
            OriData();
            GPSData();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute (Boolean result) {
            // Do ui stuff here
        }
    }
```

An [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) is even better, because it helps you avoid issues when dealing with Activity life cycles.

Comment: thank you for the reply! 
The main function is that I want to do the writefile every second.Is AsyncTaskLoader can do that? Because I never use AsyncTaskLoader before...and it seem like only can execute once in the program?